# R: sampling from a dataset based on a certain distribution centered around points in a different dataset

Tags: r, sampling

I am trying to sample rows from a set of points, df_map, in X-Y-Z space according to the distribution of the points on the X-Y plane. The mean and standard deviation of the distribution is in another dataset, df_pts.

My data looks like this

```
> df_map
   X  Y   Z
A  6  0 103
B -4  2 102
C -2 15 112
D 13  6 105
E  1 -3 117
F  5 16 105
G 10  5 103
H 14 -7 119
I  8 14 107
J -8 -4 100

> df_pts
    x   y   accuracy
a   5  18 -0.8464018
b   3   2  0.5695678
c -18  14 -0.4711559
d  11  13 -0.7306417
e  -3 -10  2.1887011
f  -9 -11  2.1523923
g   5   1 -0.9612284
h  12 -19 -0.4750582
i -16  20 -1.4554292
j   0  -8  3.4028887
```

I want to iterate through the rows in df_pts and choose one row from df_map according to Gaussian distribution of distances from the `(df_pts[i, x], df_pts[i, y])` with the 2d standard deviation being `df_pts[i, accuracy]`. In other words, at each `i = 1:10`, I want to take a sample from df_map according to normal distribution with mean `df_pts[i, x]^2 + df_pts[i, y]^2` and 2d sd `df_pts[i, accuracy]`.

I'd appreciate any suggestions for an efficient and sophisticated way of doing this. I'm relatively new to R, and coming from a C background, my way for coding tasks like this involves too many basics loops and calculations at each step using basic operations, which makes the code extremely slow.

I apologize in advance if the question is too trivial or is not well-framed.

Answer (score 1):

Easy-to-use data:

```
df_map <- data.frame(x = c(6,-4,-2,13,1,5,10,14,8,-8),
                     y= c(0,2,15,6,-3,16,5,-7,14,-4),
                     z= c(103,102,112,105,117,105,103,119,107,100))
df_pts <- data.frame(x = c(5,3,-18,11,-3,-9,5,12,-16,0),
              y= c(18,2,14,13,-10,-11,1,-19,20,-8),
              accuracy = c(-0.8464018, 0.5695678,-0.4711559,-0.7306417, 2.1887011, 2.1523923,-0.9612284,-0.4750582,-1.4554292,3.4028887))
```

What I think you are looking for is a nearest neighbour search. I have struggled A LOT with this in the past but here is the code I came up with:

```
library("FNN")

findNeighbour <- function(index){
  first = df_pts[index,1:2]
  hit = get.knnx(df_map[c("x","y")], first, k =1 )
  hit_index = hit[[1]]
  hit_result = df_map[hit_index,]
  result = append(df_pts[index,], hit_result)
}
t <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(df_map),findNeighbour))
```

which results in:

```
     x   y   accuracy x.1 y.1   z
1    5  18 -0.8464018   5  16 105
2    3   2  0.5695678   6   0 103
3  -18  14 -0.4711559  -2  15 112
4   11  13 -0.7306417   8  14 107
5   -3 -10  2.1887011  -8  -4 100
6   -9 -11  2.1523923  -8  -4 100
7    5   1 -0.9612284   6   0 103
8   12 -19 -0.4750582  14  -7 119
9  -16  20 -1.4554292  -2  15 112
10   0  -8  3.4028887   1  -3 117
```

As you can see some data is matched multiple times in this example, so depending on your goal you might want to throw these out or do a bidirectional search.

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion. I'd actually written a function that does what get.knnx does myself, but get.knnx does it much more efficiently and the code looks much nicer. Thank you!
But, this is choosing the nearest neighbor. I want to change it to choose df_map[i,] from df_map with probability p(i), where p(i) = f(distance of (df_map[i, X], df_map[i, Y]) from (df_pts[i, x], df_pts[i, y])) and f is the probability density function of gaussian distribution with mean df_pts[i, x]^2 + df_pts[i, y]^2 and 2d standard deviation df_pts[i, accuracy].

Comment: What I am trying to do is basically 
sample(df_map, 1, prob = pdf_df_map, replace = T)
with pdf_df_map being the probabilities of having (df_map[i, X], df_map[i, Y]) if the distribution of the points around (df_pts[i, x], df_pts[i, y]) is normal with 2d standard deviation df_pts[i, accuracy]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestion.

I ended up doing the following

```
df_map <- data.frame(X = c(6,-4,-2,13,1,5,10,14,8,-8),
                     Y= c(0,2,15,6,-3,16,5,-7,14,-4),
                     Z= c(103,102,112,105,117,105,103,119,107,100))
df_pts <- data.frame(x = c(5,3,-18,11,-3,-9,5,12,-16,0),
                     y= c(18,2,14,13,-10,-11,1,-19,20,-8),
                     accuracy = c(-0.8464018, 0.5695678,-0.4711559,-0.7306417, 2.1887011, 2.1523923,-0.9612284,-0.4750582,-1.4554292,3.4028887))

map.point2map <- function(map_in, pt_in) {
  dists <- dist(rbind(cbind(x = pt_in['x'],
                           y = pt_in['y']),
                     cbind(x = map_in$X,
                           y = map_in$Y)))[1:dim(map_in)[1]]

  mu <- mean(dists)
  stddev <- abs(as.numeric(pt_in['accuracy']))

  return(sample_n(tbl = map_in[, c('X', 'Y')],
                  size = 1,
                  replace = TRUE,
                  weight = dnorm(dists, mean = mu, sd = stddev)))
}

mapped <- apply(df_pts,
                1,
                function(x) map.point2map(map_in = df_map,
                                          pt_in = x))
```

and mapped is a list of 10 points sampled from df_map as desired.